# Hangfire is not executing job in manner which it is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

Here is my sample code, I'm trying to make a console app with using of below packages

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.MemoryStorage;
using System;
```

The code is like below:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();

            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ExecuteThis(1));
            
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ExecuteThis(2));
            
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ExecuteThis(3));
            
            BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ExecuteThis(4));

            using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static void ExecuteThis(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start " + number);
            Console.WriteLine("End " + number);
        }
    }
```

Expected Result:

```
Start 1
End 1
Start 2
End 2
Start 3
End 3
Start 4
End 4
```

But getting random start and end of the job, and I want to execute the next job only after completion of the previous one.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hangfire's **Continuations**:

> Continuations allow you to define complex workflows by chaining
> multiple background jobs together.

```
var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, "));
BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(id, () => Console.WriteLine("world!"));
```

In your example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseMemoryStorage();

        var id1 = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ExecuteThis(1));
        
        var id2 = BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(id1, () => ExecuteThis(2));
        
        var id3 = BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(id2, () => ExecuteThis(3));
        
        BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(id3, () => ExecuteThis(4));

        using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

There are also **Batches**, that would fit well in your case, but there are in `Pro` package.

Comment: Yes, this works in case of we have a previous job id, but in my case, this job can be called from anywhere from the app, even at the same time 2 user can perform this, so I want to ensure that whatever user called the method first, should update data first. So in simple words, just want a user to call the queue and the queue automatically manage actual execution in the background in the manner it has been called to execute, not randomly.

Comment: Isn't the updated example works in your case? What do you mean randomly called? 
Don't you know which execution is the first in the pipeline? If that's the case, maybe Hang-fire Free is not what you need, at least not by itself.

Comment: @AkashThakkar, HangFire is normally used in cases where "something" needs to be executed at regular intervals without user intervention. Looking at your comment, what you really need is a 'Queue' implementation.

Comment: That works when I know which execution in the pipeline first. But in my case, multiple users can work on the same document at the same time. So whichever is called to save first, needs to be saved first, then only it goes to queue and fetches the next one to execute.

If not hangfire in this case, then do you have any idea which queue system can be used? or any package/library?

Comment: @Thangadurai yes, I'm looking for a queue which executes my job in a queued manner. So trying with Hangfire BackgroundJob.Enqueue if it works. It is working but the execution is random, not in a manner that I enqueued.

Comment: Looking at your comments you need a [mutex or semaphore](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html#concurrency-limiters) in Hangfire. This is supported in [Hangfire Ace](https://www.hangfire.io/ace/) and must be licensed.

Comment: How many instances of the hangfire are you creating? By default i think is 10, you can limit this to 1.

Comment: `app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions { WorkerCount = 1 });`

Comment: @AkashThakkar, I think instead of the sample app, you need to clearly state the current implementation of the system, and what and where exactly the issue is. This answer provides enough information to the original question. If this not the answer, then there is something missing in your question.

Comment: @StPaulis I'm not creating instance as of now, as just creating a sample and checking It works or not. In my above code where to apply BackgroundJobServerOptions Workercount?

Comment: @Thangadurai I only have a requirement as of now, no actual code. Based on the requirement, I'm creating a console and checking that it works or not. 

The requirement is multiple user logged in at same time and can access same document at same time. So one user is updating document and that operation can be done through background queue job, which accept method execution action and execute that in a queue manner. Example, user 1 call queue and enqueue the method call, and same time user 2 is doing same. So both of that call has milisecond difference, it should be called from queue in manner

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [DisableConcurrentExecution](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/DisableConcurrentExecutionAttribute.cs#L23) attribute ?

```
    [DisableConcurrentExecution(60)]
    public static void ExecuteThis(int number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start " + number);
        Console.WriteLine("End " + number);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Comment: @AkashThakkar maybe it is related to the MemoryStorage, have you tried with a database ?

Comment: Yes, the same result. Actually it doesn't depend on Memory or DB.